# What is the purpose of the apache address binding?

Tags: networking, apache-2.4

Apache virtual host configuration files are wrapped in a container like so:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    #
    # Virtual host config etc...
    #
</VirtualHost>
```

Where the `*` represents the address of the machine apache will accept incoming requests from.
Description from the [apache binding documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/bind.html)

> When Apache starts, it binds to some port and address on the local
>   machine and waits for incoming requests. By default, it listens to all
>   addresses on the machine. However, it may need to be told to listen on
>   specific ports, or only on selected addresses, or a combination of
>   both.

I would have thought apache should "just know" it should listen on the IP address of the machine it is installed on?

What is the purpose of this address binding?
 and under what circumstances would you want to configure it to something different?

Comment: machines regularly have multiple ip addresses (even such obvious examples as your own machine - e.g. `192.168.1.2` _and_ `127.0.0.1`).

Comment: @AD7six  thanks, so why you need to specifically tell apache to *only* listen on one of the machines addresses? e.g.  `47.34.23.34` and *not* on `192.168.1.2` or `127.0.0.1`

Comment: I hoped that example alone would have turned a light on. If you e.g. tell apache (or _any_ service that listens on a port) to listen only on `127.0.0.1` - you make it accessible only to the machine itself/you. By the same logic if a server has multiple public ip addresses (which is more than common) - you limit the apache server block to traffic arriving on a particular ip address.

Comment: @AD7six good point, got it now, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose to allow configuration of Apache in a variety of deployment scenarios where you may have multiple Apache instances or multiple IP addresses and to give the admin a high degree of flexibility in how they might configure this.

Your machine may have multiple IP addresses and/or interfaces and you may only want Apache to listen and respond on some of these.  For example you may want Apache only to bind and accept requests on an internal (RFC1918) IP address and not to a publicly routable IP on the same machine.

Comment: so interfaces can have their own IP addresses, and you may need to distinguish between them? makes sense, thanks.